# $T \vdash Prov_T(\sigma)$ but $T \nvdash \sigma$

Tags: logic

If we have a consistent and axiomatizable extension of PA, which we'll call $T$, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a sentence $\phi$ such that $T \vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ but $T \nvdash \phi$ where $Prov_T(x)$ expresses "$x$ is provable in $T$".

Note very importantly that we assume $T$ contains "sufficient induction" such that it satisfies the following derivability conditions:

(1) "reflection" which is if $T \vdash \sigma$ then $T \vdash Prov_T(\sigma)$ and (2) a "formal" version of modus ponens such that $T \vdash Prov_T(a) \land Prov_T(a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow Prov_T(b)$ for any sentences $a$ and $b$.

My intuition is that there is such a sentence $\phi$ since @Noah Schweber points out in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815486/provably-unprovable-statement) that soundness might not hold.

On the other hand, I also think Lob's theorem is relevant and some adaptation of it might actually prove that $T \vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ then $T \vdash \phi$ if we use the derivability to adapt Lob's theorem. Any hints?

Comment: Isn't all extensions of PA axiomatizable?

Comment: @KennyLau not necessarily as this is an extension

Comment: @KennyLau I think the OP meant "recursively axiomatizable" (or some sort of computational assumption).

Comment: Doesn't $\phi := "0=1"$ work for $T=$ PA + "PA is inconsistent" work ?

Comment: @Max No since we are assuming $T$ is consistent.

Comment: PA + "Pa is inconsistent" is perfectly consistent, that's Gödel's incompleteness theorem

Comment: @Max Why does $T \nvdash 0 = 1$ and $T \vdash Prov_T(0 = 1)$ then?

Comment: @Max the second one I mean $T \vdash Prov_T(0 = 1)$ for the $T$ you provide?

Comment: @Rex $T$ proves "PA proves $0=1$" (since $T$ proves PA is inconsistent, and $T$ proves that inconsistent theories prove everything), and - since $T$ extends PA - $T$ proves "any proof from PA is also a proof from me;" so $T$ proves "$T$ proves $0=1$."

Comment: @Rex Max's suggestion works perfectly and is in fact the standard one.

Comment: @Noah Schweber also why are you saying here that Max's suggestion works but then you say that for a sufficiently strong theory (i.e. one that satisfies derivability conditions specified in question) that if $T \vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ then $T \vdash \phi$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber aren't you disagreeing with yourself here?

Comment: @Rex I did **not** say that if $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ then $T\vdash \phi$ - or rather if I did, it was a horrible typo. I suspect, however, that you've misread one of my remarks. Can you find a place where I said that?

Comment: @Rex What **is** true is that if $T\vdash \phi$ then $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$, but that's **not** what you've attributed to me. Unless I've made a horrible typo somewhere, I'm not disagreeing with myself anywhere.

Comment: @Were you not saying this in your second to last comment on Max's answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber We are given that if $T \vdash \phi$ then $T \vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ by the derivability condition of reflection

Comment: @NoahSchweber Do you claim that Max's counterexample satisfies the derivability conditions as required?

Comment: @Rex Yes, that's true (and I am, and it does). But the claim you've attributed to me is **the converse** - that if $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ then $T\vdash\phi$ - and that is in general **not true** (it is true for, for example, $\omega$-consistent theories, but there's no assumption here that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent). Do you recognize that the statement you've attributed to me is different from the statement in your previous-and-one comment? And again, **can you find a point where I claimed it or anything like it?**

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes I realize now you were talking about the converse which was already a precondition of the problem (property of reflection). thank you

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was pointing to you second to last comment on Max's answer with the iff statements but I believe I am mistaken

Comment: @Rex Oh god you're right, that is an **absolutely horrible** typo! The second "iff" should of course be "which implies." I'm so sorry, that's exactly the most confusing thing I could have written. I can't edit comments, but I've deleted it and added the correct version. (Incidentally, you might be interested in [the modal logic of provability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/), which both studies this type of question from a somewhat more abstract level and provides a convenient notational framework for reasoning about it.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for clarifying and for your link. I will certainly read your link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $T$ to be Peano arithmetic (PA) + the sentence "PA is inconsistent" (for instance $Prov_{PA}(0=1)$)

Then $T$ is recursively axiomatizable; and by Gödel's incompleteness theorem, $T$ is consistent (otherwise $PA \vdash Con(PA)$, and thus PA is inconsistent, which is absurd; unless PA is inconsistent, but then the whole discussion is rendered useless because there is no consistent extension of PA - anyway if we're working in ZF, PA is clearly consistent so we are content with that)

Since $T$ is consistent, and $PA \vdash \neg (0=1)$, then $T\nvdash 0=1$.

However, by very definition of $T$, $T\vdash Prov_{PA}(0=1)$ and so $T\vdash Prov_T(0=1)$ because for any recursively axiomatisable extension of PA $S$ and every $\phi$, we have $PA\vdash (Prov_{PA}(\phi) \implies Prov_S(\phi))$.

Hence we have found such a $T$.

This first part (before edit) answered the "is it possible ?" question; now if you were wondering about an arbitrary $T$ (can we find a $\phi$ for all $T$ ?), the answer is no, the best example being PA. Indeed, if $PA\vdash Prov_{PA}(\sigma)$, then $\mathbb{N}\models Prov_{PA}(\sigma)$ and so there is an actual proof in PA of $\sigma$: $PA\vdash \sigma$. In fact this argument shows that any recursively axiomatizable extension of PA that is contained in true arithmetic (the theory of $\mathbb{N}$) will have the property that there is no such $\phi$: indeed we have a soundness condition: if $\mathbb{N}\models Prov_T(\sigma)$, then $T\vdash \sigma$

Comment: You assert that $T \vdash Prov_{PA}(0 = 1)$ means that $T \vdash Prov_T(0 = 1)$, but what if $Prov_T(0 = 1)$ is independent of $T$?

Comment: That would mean that $T$ neither proves $Prov_T(0 = 1)$ nor it's negation $\neg Prov_T(0 = 1)$, which is consistent with the fact that $T$ proves $Prov_{PA} (0 = 1)$

Comment: My argument shows that it's not independent of $T$... The negation is *not* consistent with $Prov_{PA}(0=1)$ is what I'm saying

Comment: yup you're right--thanks man

Comment: your $T$ doesn't contain sufficient induction to satisfy the derivability conditions like reflection as the original problem stated

Comment: I believe the correct approach doesn't come up with a specific $T$ but rather uses a generic one and just provides a convenient sentence $\phi$.

Comment: Of course it does, because $T\vdash \sigma$ iff $PA\vdash (\neg Con(PA))\to \sigma$

Comment: Well your question was "is it possible ?". But I think it's possible to find a $\phi$ for an arbitray $T$ as well

Comment: the reflection condition requires if $T \vdash \sigma$ then $T \vdash Prov_T(\sigma)$ or are you saying if PA is reflexive then the added axiom wouldn't get in the way?

Comment: Also any thoughts about a $\phi$ for an arbitrary $T$? I'll select your answer but the intent of the question was for an arbitrary $T$-- should have been more clear.

Comment: I actually still believe that the derivability conditions I laid out in the original question are not satisfied by your $T$. How would you show if $T \vdash \sigma$ then $T \vdash Prov_T(\sigma)$?

Comment: If $T\vdash \sigma$ then $PA\vdash (\neg Con(PA))\to \sigma$ so $PA\vdash Prov_T((\neg Con(PA))\to\sigma)$ so $T\vdash Prov_T((\neg Con(PA))\to\sigma)$ and by (2) (which is also clearly satisfied by $T$ )$T\vdash Prov_T(\sigma)$. I'll try to edit my answer for an arbitrary $T$, don't accept it yet if it doesn't answer your question (but do edit your question to make it clearer !)

Comment: Actually my belief was wrong, there isn't such a $\phi$ for all $T$. See my edited answer

Comment: @Rex This is an instance of the fact that a sufficiently strong theory (including all $T$s considered here) proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence. For reasonable $T$, "$Prov_T(\phi)$" is $\Sigma_1$, so for a $T$ as in this question we have $T\vdash\phi$ iff $Prov_T(\phi)$ is true iff (since $Prov_T(\phi)$ is $\Sigma_1$ and $T$ is sufficiently strong) $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So would it be fair to say that for any consistent axiomatizable $T$ satisfying the derivability conditions, if $T \vdash \phi$, then $T \vdash Prov_T(\phi)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber and do we know this by Lob's theorem or by reflection or any other convenient method without going into proofs about $\Sigma_1$ statements?

Comment: @Rex Yes, if $T\vdash\phi$ then $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ (again, assuming that $T$ is appropriate). As far as I know, the only way to prove this is essentially by proving that $T$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete, in the sense that any proof of the claim can be easily transformed into a proof of the $\Sigma_1$-completeness of appropriate theories.

Comment: *EDIT: A previous comment of mine had a typo at the worst possible spot. I've deleted it and am writing the correct version here. This comment occurred just before Rex's comment beginning "So would it be fair..."* $$$$This is an instance of the fact that a sufficiently strong theory (including all Ts considered here) proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence. For reasonable $T$, "$Prov_T(\phi)$" is $\Sigma_1$, so for a $T$ as in this question we have $T\vdash \phi$ iff $Prov_T(\phi)$ is true, which implies (since $Prov_T(\phi)$ is $\Sigma_1$ and $T$ is sufficiently strong) $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$.

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Max's excellent answer, what we're dealing with here is that there are *many different* "niceness" properties a theory might have, and they yield different conclusions.

- **Being consistent**. 'Nuff said.
- **Being recursively axiomatizable**. This is necessary in order to even talk about provability from a theory in the language of arithmetic. *(OK that's not quite true, in general all we need is that the theory be **definable**, but working with arithmetically defined theories can lead to weird results so it's reasonable to restrict attention to recursive axiomatizations here.)*
- **Being sufficiently strong**. A theory extending PA (indeed, [even much less](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove)) has the nice property that it is $\Sigma_1$ complete: every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence is provable in the theory. This in particular implies that if $T$ is sufficiently strong (and recursively axiomatizable) then $T\vdash\phi$ implies $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ for each $\phi$.
- **Being sufficiently correct**. Consistent sufficiently strong recursively axiomatizable theories can still be quite weird - e.g. PA+$\neg$Con(PA). We have a separate interest in not-too-stupid theories - that is, theories which don't prove "blatantly false" sentences. Such theories are called "sound" - more specifically, if $T$ is a theory which proves only (not necessarily *every!*) true sentence of type $\Gamma$, then we say $T$ is **$\Gamma$-sound**. E.g. PA+$\neg$Con(PA) is **not** $\Sigma_1$ sound, since it proves the false $\Sigma_1$ sentence "$Prov_{PA}(\underline{\ulcorner 0=1\urcorner})$." Correctness is particularly relevant here, and somewhat subtle, so let me give three further comments on it:

  - First, note that *correctness* is in tension with *completeness*. To make a theory "more complete" we would *strengthen* it, while to make a theory "more correct" we would *weaken* it (by removing offending axioms).
  - Second, $\Gamma$-soundess principles aren't the only kinds of correctness which are of interest. For example, consider the following property: $$\mbox{If $T$ proves $\neg \phi(\underline{n})$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $T$ doesn't prove $\exists x\phi(x)$.}$$ *(Note that the conclusion is **not** "then $T$ proves $\forall x\neg\phi(x)$"!)* This property is called **$\omega$-consistency**. Historically this was an assumption Godel needed in his proof, which was [later removed by Rosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick). The term "consistency," rather than "soundness," in the name of the principle reflects the fact that it really is a consistency property *with respect to [a stronger-than-usual proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory). Indeed, soundness principles in general can be viewed as "higher consistency principles."
  - Finally, it's worth noting that on the face of it soundness principles can require some kind of "Platonic commitment" - to make sense of the phrase "$\Sigma_{17}$-sound," we need to (on the face of it) commit to the notion that $\Sigma_{17}$ statements have definite truth values. If we believe that $\mathbb{N}$ "exists" (???), then this is unproblematic, but the more "mathematical skepticism" we adopt can rapidly make us suspicious of even the *notion* of soundness (whereas consistency, being $\Pi_1$, is somewhat more palatable). This takes us well into foundational issues, and is really orthogonal to your question here, so I don't want to go into it in more detail - in particular, in my opinion it's best when learning the basics of this subject to at least temporarily adopt the position that $\mathbb{N}$ "really exists" and all arithmetic statements (at least) have definite truth values - but it's nonetheless worth mentioning.

---

The connection with your question is the following:

> Suppose $T$ is a consistent, recursively axiomatizable, sufficiently strong theory. Then it is possible that there is some $\phi$ such that $T\vdash Prov_T(\phi)$ but $T\not\vdash\phi$; for example, take $T$ to be PA+$\neg$Con(PA) and $\phi$ to be "$0=1$." **However**, this is ruled out if $T$ is additionally assumed to be $\omega$-consistent$^1$ or even $\Sigma_1$-sound$^2$.

$^1$This was how Godel used $\omega$-consistency in his original argument, although he could have made due with the weaker$^3$ assumption of $\Sigma_1$-soundness without changing the argument at all; I don't know when this was first observed.

$^2$Note that $\Sigma_1$-soundness and $\Sigma_1$-completeness - the latter of which follows from the assumed strength of $T$ - together imply that the $\Sigma_1$ theorems of $T$ are exactly the true $\Sigma_1$ statements, but **do not** imply that $T$ proves every true $\Pi_1$ statement, and indeed since the set of true $\Sigma_1$ statements isn't recursive we know this can't happen since $T$ is recursively axiomatizable.

$^3$Yes, $\omega$-consistency **is** strictly stronger than $\Sigma_1$ soundness! The point is that $\omega$-consistency applies to *all* $\phi$, not just to $\phi$ of a certain complexity.